# Manipulating a column in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called draft that I have scraped from Wikipedia.  I am trying to use the number of characters in a given row column (called Player), in order to divide by 2 to remove half of the row column's length in the row column field.  In other words, if row1's value in the column Player is currently in the dataframe with a value of (just an example) "Mayfield, BakerBaker Mayfield", I'd like to reduce it to simply "Mayfield, Baker".  Using the length function on the column itself does not seem to help, as the length is 256 characters consistently.  Here is how I scraped the file:

**Command 1 (Call the Package)**

```
library("rvest")
```

**Command 2 (Identify Webpage)**

```
url <- 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_NFL_Draft'
```

**Command 3 (Scrape)**

```
draft <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[4]') %>%
  html_table()

  draft <- draft[[1]]
```

This works in Excel =LEFT(E2,(LEN(E2)+1)/2)

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you

```
# I modified this to remove the first blank column, it causes errors otherwise
draft <- draft[[1]][-1]

# extract the string which follows the pattern from the original Player variable
draft %>%
  mutate(
    Player1 = substr(Player, 1, nchar(Player) / 2 + 1)
  )
```

Comment: This line replaces the dataframe with a vector of NAs instead of removing the first blank column: `draft <- draft[[1]][-1]`

Comment: The OP has a line in the code `draft <- draft[[1]]`  I replaced that line with the line you are having problems with.  You can also just do `draft <- draft[-1]` after the line in the OP's code, or (if you don't have an unnamed column with NAs straight down in your data frame), skip this entirely.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I still had the OP's line in my code and was running them both in order.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
I have removed my previous answer using a very inefficient for loop and changed it to use `sapply` instead to modify the contents of the column in question:

`draft[4] <- sapply(4, function(x,y) substr(y[,x], 1, nchar(y[,x])/2+0.5), y=draft)`

This leaves you with a modified dataframe called `draft` that preserves all the rest of the structure with only the player name contents modified.

Comment: While this code will work just fine, for loops are very slow in R.  I would strongly suggest taking advantage of vectorized functions (and `substr` is one).  These functions are implemented in a compiled language, and they do the looping there, so it's much faster.

Comment: Yes, you are right about that. I'm still learning the best ways to do things, and I had a feeling looping like this was inefficient, but I put the effort into coming up with that answer so I figured I should post it anyways. Thanks for the feedback and for the better answer!

Comment: I've used the substr() function in SAS and am very comfortable with it.  Thank you both for your quick responses.  I very much appreciate it!

Comment: Can I ask one more question please - still very new to R.  How do I take the new variable Player1 and add it to my existing df (draft)?  Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean add it in at the end, or do you wish to modify the original dataframe and replace the old incorrect column with the new correct names? The command I updated above replaces the old names with the new ones right in the same dataframe (draft). All it does it modify that single column.

Comment: I'd like to add/update the Player1 variable that Melissa created with the mutate call.

Comment: Sorry that last comment may have been confusing.  Is there an easier way to take what Melissa generated for Player1 and update the original Player field/variable in the df draft?

Comment: You can assign the results of her `mutate` call into a new variable. The result will be that you'll have a new column at the end of the dataframe called `Player1` with the updated names. If you want to overwrite the original column instead, just change `Player1` to `Player`.

Comment: I figured it out.  Here is what I used:

Comment: draft <- mutate(draft,Player = substr(Player, 1, nchar(Player) / 2 + 1))